# my push() in stack class mutates every element in the stack

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, stack

I made a stack array that based on DataRecord.
Both classes compiled without an error but when I do push() to the stack, it mutates data in every index of the stackArray[].

I cannot find which line of code make this issue.
Please helps me to find the cause, thank you.

DataRecord class:

```
public class DataRecord
{
    private String id;
    private String data;

    //default constructior
    public DataRecord( )
    {
        this.id = " ";
        this.data = " ";
    }

    //overloded constructor
    public DataRecord( String id, String data )
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }

    //set method
    public void setIDandData( String id, String data )
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }


    //get method
    public String getID()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public String getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    //toString
    public String toString()
    {
        return "\n Your ID is : " + id +
                "\n Your DataRecord is : " + data + "\n";
    }
}//End of DataRecord
```

MyStack1 class:

```
class MyStack1
{
    private int maxSize;
    private DataRecord[] stackArray;
    private int top;
    private String tempString = "";

    public MyStack1(int sizeOfStack)
    {
        maxSize = sizeOfStack;
        stackArray = new DataRecord[maxSize];
        top = -1;
    }

    public void push( DataRecord userInput )
    {
        stackArray[++top] = userInput;
    }

    public DataRecord pop()
    {
        return stackArray[top--];
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        tempString = "";

        for(int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
        {
            tempString += i+1 + stackArray[i].toString();
        }
        return "\nThe max size of the stack is : " + maxSize +
                "\nThe top index of the stack is : " + top +
                "\nThe top element of the stack is : " + stackArray[top] +
                "\nThe list of element in the stack is : " +
                "\n" + tempString;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyStack1 stackArray = new MyStack1( 5 );

        DataRecord newData = new DataRecord(" Hello "," world! ");
        stackArray.push(newData);

        System.out.println("Results : " + stackArray.toString());

        newData.setIDandData("why","omg");
        stackArray.push( newData );

        System.out.println("Results : " + stackArray.toString());

        System.out.println("pop :"+stackArray.pop().toString());
        System.out.println("pop :"+stackArray.pop().toString());
    }
}
```

[output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFvUS.png)

When I compile and run, the output looks like picture above.

Comment: yes, I edited it. thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataRecord newData = new DataRecord(" Hello "," world! ");
stackArray.push(newData);

System.out.println("Results : " + stackArray.toString());

newData.setIDandData("why","omg");
stackArray.push( newData );
```

The line `newData.setIDandData` is *modifying the object you already put in*.  You *must* explicitly create a new `DataRecord`; Java will not implicitly copy objects.  When you push `newData` into the stack, it pushes a reference to that object; modifying that object in one place will still modify the object that you've put into the stack.

There is no way around this; this is how Java works.

Comment: oh no! is there a way i can assign an object in the array

Comment: You just did, and it worked fine.  It just won't copy the object; you have to create new objects when you're inserting into the stack.

Comment: All you have to do is just use `newData = new DataRecord("why", "omg")` instead of `setIDandData`.

Comment: Are you the god of java? p.s. I like your picture

Comment: Yes.  Yes, I am the God of Java.  (http://comicattack.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/God.jpg)